# Using and creating QR codes

Tags: qr-code

Let's say I came across a QR code (in some webpage or PDF file).

How can I use it?

How do you use (and create) these QR codes?

Comment: If you don't have a smart phone, use your webcam. There are several apps out there for whatever OS you're using.

Comment: i have smartphone SE Xperia X8. So, i need Android app... Which is the best??

Comment: qr droid is pretty good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get reader software for a mobile device and scan the bar code to view the data:

[QR-Code reader](http://www.qrme.co.uk/qr-code-resources/qr-code-readers.html)

Googling ["qr code reader"](https://www.google.com/search?q=qr%20code%20reader) can give you additional results.

Googling ["qr code maker"](https://www.google.com/search?q=qr%20code%20maker) can point you in the right direction for generating QR codes.

Answer (score 2):

As for how to use QR Code, QR Code can store large amount of information, such as numbers, letters, punctuations, etc. You can scan the QR Code barcode and get the information in it. As for how to generate QR Code, it depends on what platform do you want to create in. You can [create QR Code in Excel](http://www.keepautomation.com/guide/excel_barcode_addin.html), [generate QR Code in Word](http://www.keepautomation.com/guide/word_barcode_addin.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

To use them, you can use a QR code reader application available for an Android phone/iPhone/other smartphone. You can create them using one of many QR code generators, [like this one](http://qrcode.kaywa.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create QR codes using online generators and apps - such as the ones below:

- [goqr.me](http://goqr.me)
- [qrcode.kaywa.com](http://qrcode.kaywa.com)
- [zxing.appspot.com/generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator)

You can scan QR codes on many platforms with cameras - primarily mobile. There are specialised apps for mobile platforms and web-based/Adobe AIR based apps for computers with webcams.

*All the apps below are free to download and use - some are ad-supported*

- iOS: Scan, RedLaser
- Android: QR Droid, Goggles, Barcode Scanner
- BlackBerry: ScanLife
- Adobe AIR: QRreader

QR codes can be used for many purposes, including encoding text, URLs, phone numbers, VCards, calendar events, BBM pins (BlackBerry specific) and also location co-ordinate info.

[The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) for QR Codes has a precise explanation of the use, size, types and generation of QR Codes as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the Wikipedia article doesn't explain the different types of payloads that there are (telephone number, WiFi connection data, calendar event, URL, ...) and how mobile phones recognize them.  It talks only about text vs binary vs kanji.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an online service like the [ZXing Decoder](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) to read it. Copy and paste the URL to the image or upload it.

They're supposed to have some level of redundancy, so you could even do lossy screen grabs from your PDFs too.